# Rotate BMP image java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, bmp

I can't use BufferedImage so I need to work with a two-dimensional array. Or is it better with a 3-dimensional array? 
 I just need the conditional, I think. I don't know if something is missing. I am working with 640x480 images, that's why you see those numbers in there.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Rotates {

    FileInputStream image;
    FileOutputStream img;
    byte[] header;
    byte[] datos;
    byte[] proceso;
    byte[] resultado;
    int cont;
    int i; // 
    int j;

    public Rotates(String name)throws Exception{
        this.image = new FileInputStream(name);
        this.img = img;
        this.datos = new byte[image.available()];
        this.resultado = resultado;
        this.proceso = new byte[1920];
        this.header = new byte[54];
        this.cont = 0; 
        this.i = 0; 
        this.j = 921599-1919;
    }

    public void rot()throws Exception{

        image.read(resultado);
        img = new FileOutputStream("HRotate.bmp");

        img.write(resultado);
    }
}
```

Comment: just curious... why can't you use bufferedimage?

Comment: i would gladly use BufferedImage, but it's a project we have in the faculty... So i need to do it like that.